# Ruby Array Extension

Tags: ruby, arrays

My prep work is asking me to make an array extension file and then add some methods to it. This is what they gave me:

```
describe Array do

  describe "#sum" do
    it "has a #sum method" do
      [].should respond_to(:sum)
    end

    it "should be 0 for an empty array" do
      [].sum.should == 0
    end

    it "should add all of the elements" do
      [1,2,4].sum.should == 7
    end
  end
end
```

So I've written this:

```
class Array
    def sum(array = [])
        add = 0
        if array == []
            array = add
      else
            while array.length > 0
            add = add + array.last
            array.pop
            end
            array = add
        end
        array
    end

end
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Array   #sum
    has a #sum method
    should be 0 for an empty array
    should add all of the elements (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Array#sum should add all of the elements
     Failure/Error: [1,2,4].sum.should == 7
       expected: 7
            got: 0 (using ==)
     # ./14_array_extensions/array_extensions_spec.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00241 seconds 3 examples, 1 failure
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Use `reduce(:+)`, and `map` if need be.

Comment: This is *ridiculously* complicated for something which is just a simple basic fold: `class Array; def sum; inject(0, :+) end end`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending `Array` means that you should be using `self` rather than passing in an array. Right now, you're summing an empty array (from the default parameter) rather than the array that `#sum` is called on.

Comment: Thanks for defining the problem/question.  The author of the lessons and the rspec files are not really defining in reasonable languages of what they want the students to achieve/learn.  I am sure there are many other people are as confused as the original person who asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good answer to this problem under the section "Reopen and Add to Any Class" at this site: http://www.runtime-era.com/2012/12/reopen-and-modify-ruby-classes-monkey.html

Here's the section pasted below:

**Reopen and Add to Any Class**

This type of modification can be done to any class in Ruby. This includes Gems and core Ruby classes. Let's say I wanted to be able to (naively) sum elements in my Arrays:

[1,2,3,4].sum

**#undefined method `sum' for [1, 2, 3, 4]:Array (NoMethodError)**

```
class Array

  def sum
    sum = 0
    self.each do |e|
        sum += e
    end
    sum
  end
end

[1,2,3,4].sum
```

**# 10**

Comment: While the link may answer the question, links can be broken in the future - please include the relevant details in your answer.